# web app java load resource from a file

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

I am on a dynamic web project, and I want to load a resource file.

I did this:

```
String queryTemplate = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResource(
                "test.rq"));
```

where `test.rq` exist in `src/main/resources`, but i got null pointer for on that line.

I thought maybe that src/main/resources is not the main (default) resource folder in maven, so i put this in the pom

```
<build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>

        </resources>
    </build>
```

but then my asp pages stopped working (i don't know why), so I think that there is a way to get that resources from the `src/main/resources` without changing the pom

Comment: That should be `getClass().getResource("/test.rq")` - mind the `/`, or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.rq")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
InputStream testIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.rq");
String queryTemplate = IOUtils.toString(testIn);
```

`IOUtils.toString()` appears to take an `InputStream` as input, so I used `getResourceAsStream()`.

My guess as to the null pointer is that you need to refer to the root of your classpath to access the resource file, hence I used `/test.rq`, where the slash means root.

Comment: the inputStream from java.o please ?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, but yes you need to pass an `InputStream` to `IOUtils.toString()`.